# Regarding System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to resolve the issue since long when putting code 
       
in web.config it is giving error as "**Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS**."

When removing  , it is giving error " **The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.** "
Help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<system.web>
   <trust level="Full"/>
</system.web>
```

I found this approach in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20decf81-c9a4-40de-a074-e354077be643/error-systemsecuritysecurityexception-request-for-the-permission-of-type?forum=clr&prof=required).

Also I'd suggest you reading https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320268

**UPDATE 1:**

As said in the [FIX: How to resolve Security Exception (ASP.NET)?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555466), Add the following lines of code to machine.config file. This file can be located under the folder - `Root Drive Name:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\CONFIG`

```
<location path="yourdomain.com" allowOverride="true">
 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/> //Referred from https://www.codeproject.com/questions/586223/securityplusexceptionpluscomingplusinplusaplusrunn
  <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: when i am adding <trust level="Full"/>, then it is generating error as "Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Comment: have a look at Solairaja's answer in [Virtual Directory not being configured as an application in IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1938797/5588347).

Comment: No Still problem persists, i tried with <authentication mode ="None"></authentication> but no success. Offline complete website is working fine but online it is generating issue.

Comment: I believe its a configuration issue. have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: when i am adding <trust level="Full"/> it is showing  following inputs on the screen as Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
 My folder is configured as IIS & it is working fine on local server.

Comment: `Clean` the project. then go to **project properties -> Web -> Create Virtual Directory.** that should resolve the error.

Comment: No ways i am not able to resolve. My web server has two folders having same software. At a time either of the folder works. But each has been configured as independent folders for specific website. I am completely helpless... what to do? snehbandhan.co.in here error is generating and dnyanarjan.com/frmmemberlogin.aspx is working is fine.